# How can I tell through the Stripe API if a connected account is complete?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am trying to verify that a user on my website has completed the onboarding process with Stripe through their API. I don't see any fields in the Accounts object (https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts) that tells me if their account is Complete.  If it's not complete, they shouldn't be allowed to do certain things on my website.

Using PHP. Stripe connected accounts are "Standard" accounts. (not express or custom)

In my Stripe dashboard, I see the statuses of "complete", "pending", "restricted", etc. I'm trying to find that field through the API.
[img of stripe dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM0MM.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A connected account in Stripe is considered verified if charges and payouts are enabled on the account:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-charges_enabled
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-payouts_enabled

If both of those properties on the account object are `true` then you can consider the account verified/complete and ready for any requests from your platform. Otherwise, if either of those two fields are false it implies that the account has outstanding or pending requirements in their requirements hash (i.e., pending | restricted):

https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements

Comment: Thank you! I can get those two fields and verify.